# How to get current format that has been set in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker. While initializing, I use the option `"format": "dd-M-yyyy"`.

```js
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  weekStart: 0,
  format: "dd-M-yyyy",
  autoclose: true
});
```

I have some related functions to be called when the date is modified. Within these functions, I need to get the currently used date format for some validation purposes. The jQuery UI datepicker allows us to get the current format using:

```js
var format = $("#to_dt").datepicker("option", "dateFormat");
```

I have tried using `var format = $("#to_dt").datepicker("option", "format")`, but it returns object.